# "Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo" warning when running pod install

Tags: cocoapods, warnings

After I ran `pod install`, I got a warning that said:

> [!] Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo. Since CDN is now used as the default, you may safely remove it from your repos directory via `pod repo remove master`.
>
> To suppress this warning please add `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false` to your Podfile.

Why did I get this warning? Previously, I was able to ran `pod install` without any warnings.

Here's another detail if that's helpful: I wasn't able to use `sudo gem install` to install/upgrade CocoaPods, so I used this command instead:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: I am also having this issue. Is it a good to to what the accepted answer says? In my mind it sounds like a bad idea to remove a repo called 'master'...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run the command `pod repo remove master`

Comment: This results in the following output: ` [!] repo master does not exist`

Comment: It has relation to this change which removes git repo and makes trunk default repository https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/8923  I have solved the problem by listing repos 'pod repo list' and then removing master  'pod repo remove'  leaving only trunk

Comment: For me `pod repo remove cocoapods`

Comment: For me this worked too not the - pod repo remove cocoapods

Answer (score 176):

When running the 'pod repo remove master' I was greeted with:

```
[!] repo master does not exist
```

I did a ....

```
pod repo list

cocoapods
- Type: git (master)
- URL:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
- Path: /Users/plasma/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods

trunk
- Type: CDN
- URL:  https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
- Path: /Users/plasma/.cocoapods/repos/trunk
```

Noticed the 'master' is actually called 'cocoapods' so then I did a..

```
pod repo remove cocoapods
```

One that had completed I was able to do update and install without any errors.

Comment: Nice. This not only fixed the warning but also recovered multiple gigabytes of disk space! 

Answer (score 18):

You should now use the CocoaPods CDN as the default source:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

and if so, you can safely delete the master repo from your machine, with the suggested command `pod repo remove master`.

*Original Answer*

I resolved this warning by adding a `source` to the top of my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Comment: Sure this gets rid of the warning, but you want cocoapods to use the CDN not use the old specs repo: https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.2/

Comment: nice, resolved my terminal warning.

Comment: thanks @AlanZeino good point, have updated the answer

Answer (score 17):

If you have the error:

```
[!] repo master does not exist
```

It's will work if you try this:

```
pod repo remove cocoapods
```

Don't worry it's will not remove your pods :)

Answer (score 12):

[I would recommend following Plasma's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66088922/3151675) However, if you don't want to delete the master repo, just mute the warning by adding the `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo` setting to your Podfile by changing this:

```
install! 'cocoapods'
```

to this:

```
install! 'cocoapods', :warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false
```

If you already have an option after `install! 'cocoapods'`, append the new setting with a comma:

```
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false, :warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false
```

Answer (score 4):

It has relation [to this change](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/8923) which removes git repo and makes `trunk` default repository  I have solved the problem by listing repos `pod repo list` and then removing master using the command `pod repo remove` leaving only trunk

Answer (score 3):

```sh
# pod version > 1.7.2
# Step 1
pod repo list

# pod repo list result:
# cocoapods
# - Type: git (remotes/origin/master)
# - URL:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
# - Path: /Users/apple/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods

# trunk
# - Type: CDN
# - URL:  https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
# - Path: /Users/apple/.cocoapods/repos/trunk

# Step 2
pod repo remove cocoapods

# result
# Removing spec repo `cocoapods`
```

It's working for me.