# `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false` causes syntax errors

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

Recently I've been working on two iOS projects. One of them has `source` commands in the Podfile, and the other doesn't. The Podfile for the latter looks something like this:

```rb
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Foo', '~> 1.2'
  pod 'Bar', '~> 5.4'
  # ...etc
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I run `pod install` for that project, I get a warning about an unused master specs repo, but it says to add `warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false` to disable the warning. So I do:

```rb
platform :ios, '12.0'

warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false # this is new

# ...
```

Now, I get a syntax error when I try to `pod install`. I don't know Ruby, so I can't diagnose the problem myself very well.

I already found ["Your project does not explicitly specify the CocoaPods master specs repo" warning when running pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65407287/your-project-does-not-explicitly-specify-the-cocoapods-master-specs-repo-warni). The accepted answer says to remove the master specs repo, which isn't a viable solution in my case -- like I said at the beginning, I'm working on another project which specifies `source`, and whenever I run `pod install` there the warning will just come back.

I also found that `:warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo` (with a colon) is an option for the `install!` command, which might look like this:

```rb
install! 'cocoapods', :warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false
```

but I don't currently have an `install!` command, and I'm not sure what the consequences of adding one would be. (Google has been unhelpful here, as the results are more about the `pod install` shell command than the `install!` Ruby command.)

Why does the warning suggest something that isn't allowed, and what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `install! 'cocoapods', :warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo => false`

An empty `install! 'cocoapods'` command is implicit for any Podfile. More info in the [Podfile guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html).

Comment: Does it matter where in the Podfile the `install!` command goes? Intuitively I want to put it between the `target` and `post_install` sections, which seems to work, but I want to be sure that doesn't have unintended side effects.

Comment: I don't think it matters. The only change in behavior from not having the line in the file is disabling the warning.